# What should the [research] tag be used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, I don't know what it's being used for<sup>1</sup>. What should it be used for? Should we burninate it?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Actually, it looks like its being used both for research claims and when people want to find something out.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I think it is used when the question is about some specific research or study, or it expects some authoritative study references from the answers.

[Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) has similar tag and it's described as:

> Questions directly focused on performing academic research applicable to any discipline.
>
> This tag is only for questions that are directly about research. Do not use it for questions tangentially related to research.
>
> For example, if you are asking about how to best cite something, you are probably doing so because you are publishing your research. Such a question would only be **related** to research, but not about it, and should thus not be tagged [research](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research). If you are however asking, e.g., how to best organise your research, the question is actually **about** research and thus should be tagged [research](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research).